# How do terminal multiplexers spoof keyboard input for S-Lang-based console apps?

Tags: input, terminal, tmux, s-lang

I am experimenting with wrapping console applications into a synthetic environment like I though multiplexers do. But I've noticed that apps like `mc` (midnight commander) written with the use of S-Lang library are able to get partial keyboard state even if their `stdin` is not attached to TTY.
For example, `cat /dev/zero|/usr/bin/mc` doesn't affect the operability of the app at all.

I tried to understand how does mc works in tmux but I cannot find the place where does the magic happen in the code of these three components (mc, tmux and slang).

The question is how can I programmatically start an app like `mc` so that I would be able to interact with it via file descriptor while the actual stdin won't be available to that app at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're checking if their *standard input* comes from a terminal, using **`isatty`**, and if not closing the input, reopening **`/dev/tty`**.

Unless an application takes special actions in that sort of approach, the piped input is lost.  For instance, it could read the data into a buffer and do something useful with it.

Comment: Got it. There lays the whole layer I was not aware of. I was able to check it with `python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("mc", stdin_read=lambda x: 0)'` - mc doesn't respond to anything. Great!